# Where is the GNU checksum file format defined?

Tags: gnu, hashsum, checksum

Where is the GNU checksum file format defined?

I don't see any mention of the `checksum` file format at the [GNU documentation website](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the `sha2` utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sha2-utilities) points to the [documentation for `md5sum`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#md5sum-invocation) which says

> For each *file*, ‘`md5sum`’ outputs by default, the MD5 checksum, a space, a flag indicating binary or text input mode, and the file name. Binary mode is indicated with ‘`*`’, text mode with ‘’ (space). Binary mode is the default on systems where it’s significant, otherwise text mode is the default. If *file* contains a backslash or newline, the line is started with a backslash, and each problematic character in the file name is escaped with a backslash, making the output unambiguous even in the presence of arbitrary file names.

The checksum files are simply the output of the corresponding utilities, so the above documents their format too.